# How to dynamically add widgets to a GridLayout within a TabbedPanelItem

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on an application that will sequentially add Labels and CheckBoxes into a GridLayout that is itself inside a TabbedPanelItem. There are two TabbedPanelItems which will remain static, and I wish to create a third which has its content supplied from a local database.

I'm not sure how I can create this new TabbedPanelItem with python without having to re-create the entire screen.

I have a class, Screen2(Screen) which (I think) controls the output from the Kivy. My trouble is I can't seem to access the TabbedPanel, and every time I add a widget it is overlayed on the entire App whereas I want to instead have it within the content of a new tab.

```
<Screen2>:

    FloatLayout:

        TabbedPanel:
            do_default_tab: False

            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "TAB 1"

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    id: info

                    ScrollView:

                        GridLayout:
                            id: container
                            cols: 2
                            size_hint_y: 1
                            padding : 30,30
                            spacing: 10, 10
                             .
                             .
                             .
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "TAB2"
```

```py
class Screen2(screen):
    def create_dyn_tab(self):
        panel = TabbedPanel()
        menuTab = TabbedPanelHeader(text="Menu")
        panel.add_widget(menuTab)

        menuContent = []

        menuTab.content = ScrollView(GridLayout(cols=2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution showed how to access `TabbedPanel`, and dynamically adding a new `TabbedPanelItem` within Python script.

## kv file

- Add `id: tp` to `TabbedPanel:`

### Snippets

```
<Screen2>:
    tp: tp

    FloatLayout:

        TabbedPanel:
            id: tp
            do_default_tab: False
```

## py  file

- Initiate `ScrollView` widget and assigned it to variable, `sv`
- Assigned initiated `ScrollView` widget to `content` of `menuTab`
- Add `GridLayout` as child of `ScrollView`

### Snippets

```
def create_dyn_tab(self):
    menuTab = TabbedPanelHeader(text="Menu")
    self.tp.add_widget(menuTab)
    sv = ScrollView()
    menuTab.content = sv
    container = GridLayout(cols=2)
    sv.add_widget(container)
    for i in range(8):
        container.add_widget(Label(text='Label'+str(i)))
        container.add_widget(CheckBox())
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I guess I got a little ahead of myself trying to pre-make the tab. 

How could I go about calling this function upon switching screens? Is it best to attach the function to a button, or is there a way to have it called when the screen is switched?

Comment: In kv file, assuming *Screen2* is given a `name: 'screen2'`. After switching screen, use `root.manager.get_screen('screen2').create_dyn_tab()` to access method `create_dyn_tab()`.

Comment: I called it within the __init__ method. Is that considered bad practice? It seems to work, but I don't have a strong background in OOP to know what is considered incorrect.

Comment: It is not a bad practice to put it in the `init` or constructor method of `class Screen2`. When an object is instantiated, it always invoke the `init` method.